# How to search snippet description in vscode 1.54

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I use vscode 1.43 and just use `ctrl shift p` -> `Insert snippet` and can search both the shortcut and description

When update to 1.54 it only search the shortcut

How to enable search the description of the snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this recently too.  It should work see this issue providing the functionality: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/31768

So I went ahead and filed an issue on it: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/119261

You should go and upvote it.

---

UPDATE: This has been fixed in the Insiders Build as of today (March 22, 2021) and I have tested it.  Should be in v1.55 due out in early April, 2021.

---

And the fix is in v1.55 released 03/31/2021.

Comment: Okay. Currently I return to 1.43.